# Parsing with awk by modifying the field and record separators

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file which is as follows:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
49515 23/6/2014 SL B                                              .OO                                  2500.00
          R ROY                             4561235
BEING THE T.E PAID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
23495 26/7/2014  CL A                                     2300.00                                         .00
          S DAS                             2334167
BEING THE MONEY RECOVERED 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My desired output is as follows:

```
49515 23/6/2014  SL B                      .00                2500.00       R ROY          4561235        BEING THE T.E PAID
23495  26/7/2014  CL A             2300.00                        .00       S DAS          2334167       BEING THE MONEY RECOVERED
```

I tried the following code in awk without much success, the idea being to set newline as field separator and the line of hyphens (--------) as the record separator:

```
BEGIN {
   FS="/n"
   RS="^-+$"}
{ print $1,$2,$3}
```

Comment: The `FS=/n"` is just a typo, right? You were using `FS="\n"`?

Comment: Did the answers solved your problem? We can't know for sure until one answer gets accepted.

Answer (score 3):

This should work for your needs:

```
awk '/---/ {print buff; buff="";} /[^-]/{buff=buff" "$0}'  filename
```

You can use if-else blocks too:

```
awk '{if($0 ~ /---/){print buff; buff=""} else {buff=buff" "$0}}' filename
```

Also without using a buffer:

```
awk '{if($0 !~ /---/){printf "%s ", $0} else print ""}' filename
```

Comment: Nice. You might want to only print unless `NR==1` though to avoid printing a blank line at the beginning.

Comment: True, but I thought a shorter code would be better (and easier to understand) than the one adding this extra checking just because of an extra blank line. Thanks for the comment though.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there:

```
$ awk -F'\n' -vRS="-+\n" '($1){print $1,$2,$3; }' file
49515 23/6/2014 SL B                                              .OO                                  2500.00           R ROY                             4561235 BEING THE T.E PAID
23495 26/7/2014  CL A                                     2300.00                                         .00           S DAS                             2334167 BEING THE MONEY RECOVERED
```

Or, if you prefer the BEGIN block:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n"; RS="-+\n"}($1){print $1,$2,$3; }' file
```

The problem (assuming the `/n` was a typo) was that you were using `^` and `$` in the definition of `RS`. I'm not sure about the internals of how the `RS` regex is implemented but I would guess that they actually refer to the beginning and end of the file, not the line. As a workaround, I set `RS` to a stretch of `-` ending in a newline. However, this means that it will break if you can have one or more `-` at the end of a line. I don't know how to match from the beginning since `\n-+\n` fails for the first line.

A similar approach would be to replace `^-+$` with a blank line and use perl's paragraph mode:

```
$ sed 's/--*/\n/' file | perl -F'\n' -00ane 'print "@F\n";' 
49515 23/6/2014 SL B                                              .OO                                  2500.00           R ROY                             4561235 BEING THE T.E PAID
23495 26/7/2014  CL A                                     2300.00                                         .00           S DAS                             2334167 BEING THE MONEY RECOVERED
```